# With Azure SDK 1.8 how do I Enable Intellitrace?

Tags: azure, azure-web-roles

I am desperately trying to figure out why my Azure web role keeps re-cycling. I upgraded from MVC3 to MVC4 and it seems to be broken.

All the event log offers is

> The application '/' belonging to site '1' has an invalid AppPoolId
>   'DefaultAppPool' set.  Therefore, the application will be ignored.

And

```
The application '/' belonging to site '1273337584' has an invalid AppPoolId
```

Most suggestions have been followed however I can't figure out how to enable Intellitrace in the publish dialog that came with SDK 1.8? The Enable Intellitrace checkbox doesn't seem to be there anymore.

Any ideas how to use Intellitrace now?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are asking for how to enable Intellitrace with MVC4 web role in Azure SDK, you just need to set it in the **Publish Window > Settings > Advance Settings** as below:

[image]

Comment: Intellitrace option is missing. It used to be there

Comment: Was it enabled before, also if you go to VS Tools > Options > Intellitrace, can u find it enabled? Do u have VS prof or above as well.

Comment: Maybe that is it. My home machine only has VS 2012 Prof. No intellitrace options in the menu either. Any other ideas on how to debug this. I've been at this 16 hours and just have no clue how to figure out why it isn't deploying.

Comment: What u can do is, enable the RDP access to your published package and redeploy it. After deployment RDP to your Azure VM and look for the problem in event log, IIS settings etc. You sure can run all the test scenario once RDP to Azure VM.

Comment: Also if you decided to do Remote Debugging you can use this article as well: http://fullscale180.com/Blog/post/2012/10/07/Remote-Debugging-Windows-Azure-Cloud-Services-with-Visual-Studio-2012.aspx

Comment: Signed up for Azure support. It wasnt even deploying to IIS. I was left clueless and they haven't figured out yet so I guess it wasn't straight forward.  Thanks for help.